# Will changing my Amazon Affiliate links affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, links, affiliate, amazon

I recently downloaded the plug-in Eazy Azon to enable geo-linking for my Amazon Affiliates.

I have one post in particular that is highly ranked on Google. According to Easy Azon, I need to replace all my existing Amazon Affiliate links (there are many) with their links. I do have readers in other countries so allowing them to click to their home Amazon sites would be very helpful and hopefully profitable for me.

If I keep the content the same, keep the products the same, but only change the links to reflect Eazy Azon's linking, will this have any affect on my SEO? They said no, but I want to be 100 percent sure.

Comment: My comment is not your answer, but you should use nofollow attribute on such links, then you'll be SEO tension free from affliate links, redirect links, comment links etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing how your page behaves, every change will have an impact , for worse or better, at SEO level.

As it has already been suggested, that kind of links should be annotated with the `nofollow` property, as its definition suggests:

> The nofollow keyword indicates (...) that the link to the
>   referenced document was included primarily because of a commercial
>   relationship between people affiliated with the two pages.

That doesn't guarantee it will perform better, but in the right way.

Comment: While you are correct that any change could alter rankings, I wouldn't expect that changing affiliate links would generally make rankings shift in any noticeable way.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree that just using the `nofollow` tag won't change rankings dramatically (besides it's recommended to use in these cases), but using that plugin adds also javascript which changes how your page behaves, that can impact in some way depending how is done.

Comment: It sounds like the content is going to be the same.    I've never seen JavaScript updates effect rankings unless they inhibit crawlers.